# How to find dataframe after it is generated in a for-loop using dictionary values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a function that creates 3 data frames then takes the element wise-average of the three. The data frames are generated from a loop using a dictionary that was defined in an earlier step, like this:

```
# extracting and organizing data
def density_dataP(filenames):
    datasets = ["df_1", "df_2", "df_3"]

    for num in filenames:
        for index in range(len(datasets)):
            datasets[index] = pd.DataFrame({
                              #excluding the edges b/c nothing interesting happens there
                    "z-coordinate (nm)": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[num]["water"])._auxdata_values[7:43:1,0], 
                    "water": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[num]["water"])._auxdata_values[7:43:1,1],
                    "acyl": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[num]["acyl"])._auxdata_values[7:43:1,1],
                    "headgroups": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[num]["head"])._auxdata_values[7:43:1,1],
                    "ester": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[num]["ester"])._auxdata_values[7:43:1,1],
                    "protein": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(filenames[num]["proa"])._auxdata_values[7:43:1,1]
                     })
    master_data = (df_1 + df_2 + df_3)/3
    return master_data
```

However, when I try to run the function with a valid input I get the following error:

```
---> 16     master_data = (df_1 + df_2 + df_3)/3
     17     return master_data

NameError: name 'df_1' is not defined
```

The inputs into the XVGReader method needs the path to an XVG file for the input and  I have those contained in the dictionary. The first layer of the dictionary has a number, the second layer has the path to the file. Each number is associated with all the paths in one of the three dataframes.(i.e. all paths in key 1 are for df_1, etc.) The dictionary I am using looks roughly like this:

{1: {'water': $PATH_TO_water1.xvg', 'acyl': $PATH_TO_acyl1.xvg', 'head': $PATH_TO_head1.xvg', 'ester': $PATH_TO_ester1.xvg', 'proa': $PATH_TO_proa1.xvg'},

2: {'water': $PATH_TO_water2.xvg', 'acyl': $PATH_TO_acyl2.xvg', 'head': $PATH_TO_head2.xvg', 'ester': $PATH_TO_ester2.xvg', 'proa': $PATH_TO_proa2.xvg'},

3: {'water': $PATH_TO_water3.xvg', 'acyl': $PATH_TO_acyl3.xvg', 'head': $PATH_TO_head3.xvg', 'ester': $PATH_TO_ester3.xvg', 'proa': $PATH_TO_proa3.xvg'}}

How do I get python to recognize the DataFrames created in this loop or at least get the final result of master_data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, "df_1" is a string in the list `datasets`, not a variable. If you want to access by name, then you would want `datasets` to be a dict with a key of `df_1`, etc. and the value a dataframe.

But you don't need to name items here because all you want is an average.
So I think you should simplify the function. For example, the inner loop over `datasets` seems to create three copies of the same value; that seems like it can be omitted. Also, if filenames is a `dict` where each value is a dataframe, so you can iterate over the values directly.

```
def density_dataP(filenames):
    datasets = []
    for df in filenames.values():
        datasets.append(pd.DataFrame({                             
                    "z-coordinate (nm)": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(df["water"])._auxdata_values[7:43:1,0], 
                    "water": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(df["water"])._auxdata_values[7:43:1,1],
                    "acyl": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(df["acyl"])._auxdata_values[7:43:1,1],
                    "headgroups": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(df["head"])._auxdata_values[7:43:1,1],
                    "ester": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(df["ester"])._auxdata_values[7:43:1,1],
                    "protein": mda.auxiliary.XVG.XVGReader(df["proa"])._auxdata_values[7:43:1,1]
                     })
    return pd.concat([datasets]).mean()
```

Comment: Using a dict of dicts instead of a list for 'datasets' worked. Thank you for the recommendation.